# Change form input data-bind value

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, knockout.js

I have a form in Laravel using Knockout.js, the input data-bind gets the last data from mysql. Everything works fine but a simple textfield to write in some values for the data is not what I want and a multiselect is not working for me.

I've searched for something to add values to this textfield and I've found the TextExt plugin. Now I can add some values like on this site the Tags field and save them.
In TextExt JS I can set the tagged values on page startup with

```
tagsItems: {{ $title->language }},
```

title->language get the Data from mysql and shows it as tags, but now I have the tagged values on startup and the data-bind value with the same data only as text and I need to delete them first before I can edit it.

Is there a way to hide the value from the data-bind or clear it on startup? Here is the form code I'm using

```
<input type="text" id="language" class="text-core" data-bind="value: app.models.title.language, valueUpdate: 'keyup' " placeholder="Language">

**edit** this is the working form

{{ Form::label('language', trans('dash.language')) }}
{{ Form::text('language', Input::old('language'), array('class' => 'text-core')) }}
```

When I delete the data-bind value I can't update the data.
I found something to clear the textfield on focus, but I want the tagged values on start because the data-bind value is only shown as text.

Have you some ideas how to do this?